# JUser::getParameters in Joomla 3.0

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

In joomla 1.5.X I used `JUser::getParameters($loadsetupfile=false, $path=...);` to load the user parameters from custom xml.

In Joomla3.0 JUser::getParameters() has been removed. See the [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#JUser).

It says to use [getParam](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJUser/getParam), but it doesn't support path parameter.

So how I can load the user parameters in Joomla3.0 ?

Comment: Can you explain what you ultimately want to achieve? What are these parameters that you want to load. There may be other ways to achieve what you want to do in J 3.0

Comment: Sure. I need to load custom user parameters(text and radio types), so they appear in User Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You do this with a plugin now. Did you try searching Google for

add custom fields to joomla user profile

The first hits explain it. Actually there is a question open on this one over at:
[Creating Joomla user profile plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029699/creating-joomla-user-profile-plug-in)